# ASP.NET WebAPI 2: How to pass empty string as parameter in URI

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, null, query-string

I have a function like this in my `ProductsController`:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetProduct(string id)
{
    var product = products.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.Id == id);
    return Ok(product);
}
```

When I send a GET request with this URL:

```
 api/products?id=
```

it treats `id` as null. How can I make it to treat it as an empty string?

Comment: GetProduct(string id = string.Empty)

Comment: Use optional parameter `string id = ""` then you can call `GET api/products/`

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute.convertemptystringtonull(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Ric What if i want GET api/products to return an error? Because I think it will be ambiguous

Comment: ambiguous in what sense? it depends how you have setup your routing etc and if you are uring resful api,

Comment: @Ric I afraid that people may think GET api/products will return all products.

Comment: I would also think the same!

Answer (score 11):

This

```
public IHttpActionResult GetProduct(string id = "")
{
    var product = products.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.Id == id);
    return Ok(product);
}
```

or this:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetProduct(string id)
{
    var product = products.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.Id == id ?? "");
    return Ok(product);
}
```

Comment: For me it just worked when adding a default value to the parameter in the method signature.

Answer (score 4):

I have a situation where I need to distinguish between no parameter passed (in which case default of null is assigned), and empty string is explicitly passed. I have used the following solution (.Net Core 2.2):

```
[HttpGet()]
public string GetMethod(string code = null) {
   if (Request.Query.ContainsKey(nameof(code)) && code == null)
      code = string.Empty;

   // ....
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Looks like the behavior is different in .NET Framework and .NET Core. The former allows you to pass in an empty string.